# Open vimeo application via URL

Tags: android, eclipse, url

This code takes me to the browser, I have the vimeo application, how can it go to the vimeo application?

```
vimeo1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705?"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);
            }
        });
```

EDITED

```
vimeo1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                try{
                     Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                     Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705"));
                     browserIntent.setPackage("com.vimeo.android.videoapp");
                     startActivity(browserIntent);
                  }
                catch(Exception e){
                    // App is not Installed
                    //Navigate to Play Store or display message                         
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, set package name while Re-directing.

catch block will be called if no app is installed related to that package.

```
try{
     Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
     Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705"));
     browserIntent.setPackage("com.vimeo.android.videoapp");
     startActivity(browserIntent);
  }
catch(Exception e){
    // App is not Installed
    //Navigate to Play Store or display message                         
}
```

**Edit**

I have checked this and you were right its not working. I changed into my code. Now its opening Application but video is not running, I don't know why.
Check this updated code.

```
try{
   Intent browserIntent = null;
   PackageManager pmi = getPackageManager();
   browserIntent =     pmi.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.vimeo.android.videoapp");
   browserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705"));

   startActivity(browserIntent);
}
catch(Exception e){
   // App is not Installed
   //Navigate to Play Store or display message
   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "In Catch Block", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: I write it as in the EDITED part, I can't click on it :/

Comment: What do you mean you can't click on it.

If you say nothing happens I'm 90% sure you don't have the official app installed.

Comment: I have it installed from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vimeo.android.videoapp and the link stopped doing anything at all!

Comment: @Roa Check this updated code, Its navigating to app but video is not working

Comment: It takes me to Vimeo application but it doesn't open the URL or any other!

Answer (score 1):

With the official Vimeo app you can do this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705")));
```

While this looks almost identical to your code, aside from lack of a `?`, on my Android phone it works fine (opens the Vimeo app).

Comment: I changed it, it went to the browser, I removed the startActivity(browserIntent); iy also went to the browser ... it didn't work, can you please write the entire Java code?

Comment: Are you sure you have the official Vimeo client installed and have opened / used it before? It just seems like it hasn't registered its url handler yet.

Answer (score 1):

We actually recently made a [vimeo-deeplink-android](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-deeplink-android) library which should help you achieve exactly what you're looking to do.

You could include it with gradle:

`compile 'com.vimeo.android.deeplink:vimeo-deeplink:1.0.0'`

And then deeplink to your video with [this method](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-deeplink-android#view-a-video-in-the-vimeo-app):

`boolean handled = VimeoDeeplink.showVideoWithUri(Context context, String videoUri)`

Where `videoUri` is equal to `/videos/83178705`.