# A link to vimeo application but

Tags: android, eclipse, hyperlink, vimeo, vimeo-android

I have asked what is the code that sends a link from the application that I'm making to the vimeo application; it opens vimeo application but not the video specified in the link, does anybody knows how?

```
vimeo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
          try{
              Intent browserIntent = null;
              PackageManager pmi = getPackageManager();
              browserIntent =     pmi.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.vimeo.android.videoapp");
                   browserIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                   browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705"));
                   startActivity(browserIntent);                     
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705"));
                    startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            }
      });
```

Comment: What happened when clicking the button ? Really it doesn't go to this link http://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705 ?

Comment: The link was wrong, I put the right one and I didn't select anything!

Comment: Ok, I removed the 7th line and it goes by the browser, that's the second option, not the first :(

Comment: You want your link to open in vimeo app right ? but unfortunately it doesn't opens with your link ?

Comment: When I tick on the link, it takes me to the vimeo application, (not the browser) but not to this link http://player.vimeo.com/video/83178705

Comment: Do you want to open it in browser with that link ? or in vimeo app with your link ?

Comment: No, first thing, player.vimeo.com/video/83178705 opens in the vimo application, if I don't have the vimeo application, it opens player.vimeo.com/video/83178705 on the browser.

Comment: Okay,Now is it not opening in vimeo app (with your link) ?

Comment: No it's not, it goes to the browser., just in case, I have the application from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vimeo.android.videoapp

Comment: Ok, give me sometime.

Comment: Take your time... If it's helpful to you then accept and upvote my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing this below, it will reset all your app preference

Go to **Settings->Apps**, choose from menu **Reset app preferences** and confirm Reset apps.

After that,
 choose it in **Settings->Apps** and press **Clear defaults** button for vimeo app

Now try to open that video link(vimeo link) again. Now it'll ask you to select which app to use. Then select your vimeo app as default

Comment: This is an awkward question, where is the settings? :)

Comment: go to default mobile settings

Comment: Vinoth, forgive me, I still don't know how. Are you mentioning the mobile or the Eclipse?

Comment: Copy your apk and install it on mobile....Then try it with real device not the emulator

Comment: I did what you asked on my smartphone, I installed my application and when I hit the link to vimeo, it goes to the application but stll :/

Comment: Is it asking which application you wanna use at the moment of clicking the link? Or is it directly gonna vimeo app without asking ?

Answer (score 2):

I answered your other question with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36049334/1759443). But I believe it will fix this issue as well since our [vimeo-deeplink](https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-deeplink-android/) library accommodates opening our specific application.

You could include it with gradle:

```
compile 'com.vimeo.android.deeplink:vimeo-deeplink:1.0.0'
```

And then deeplink to your video with this method:

```
boolean handled = VimeoDeeplink.showVideoWithUri(Context context, String videoUri)
```

Where `videoUri` is equal to `/videos/83178705`.